# How to set height of my web page in html5

Tags: css, html

I have been created simple webpage using html5,css and js.

I have header,menu,slide show,main-content and footer. and also using sticky side-bar

After all coding, slideshow display at the middle of main content and main-content also hidden.

css code for slideshow,main-content and footer:

```
#wowslider-container1 {
position: absolute !important;
-webkit-transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
left: 50%;
top: 60%;
opacity: 1;
}

/* clearfix */
.clearfix:before, .clearfix:after {
content: "";
display: table;
}
.clearfix:after {
clear: both;
}
.clearfix {
zoom: 1;
}
/* Main ................ */
main {
margin: 20px auto;
max-width: 940px;
}
/* aside */
aside {
float: left;
max-width: 220px;
}
.inside {
background-color: #000;
padding: 10px;
}
#sidebar.sticky {
float: none;
position: fixed;
top: 20px;
z-index: 6;
left: auto;
}
/* main content */
.main_content {
float: right;
max-width: 700px;
color:#fff;
}
/* Footer .............. */
footer {
background-color: #999;
height: 300px;
width: 100%;
}
```

My page look like this: http://s14.postimg.org/jw2uimt9t/Untitled_1_copy.png

I have lots of file, how to fix my problem, there anyone help me to fix this.

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the question/problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess i understood what you need,
most of the div containers that you use don't have css size properties like width and height, but most importantly they don't have a position values in order to fit a html layout structure.

try using position:relative; first on the css for the most important elements of the page.

start first with this default css parameters:

```
body, html {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;     
}
```

then add to your slideshow css main class this

```
*your_slideshow_class_name_here {
position: relative;
}
```

after that, things become easier to solve

Comment: Thanks @drukaman, now page look like this, http://s9.postimg.org/ls5rh9d4v/Untitled_1_copy.png. slideshow placed after menu-bar, that's correct. but after that the main-content is hidden. that is need to be show after slideshow..

Comment: now is way easier to solve the rest of your problems, you need to set the position parameters for the rest of the elements that you want to change.  try putting again position:relative for the text container on the css

Comment: still from your answer, i used only body, html {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;     
}.. not use position property. if i use position:relative for slideshow,it shows like this,http://s2.postimg.org/hppn4drc9/Untitled_1_copy.png.. that is menu and logo are hidden..

Comment: what i mean is, that you need to have an individual div container for every element of your page, what you have now at the moment?  a top menu, a slideshow, html text, what else?    that html text need an individual div container, then afterwards you will need to control its position in on the html layout. you don't need to change the slideshow position property

Comment: it would be easier if you could post or publish this work in progress somewhere online , so people could help you.  it seems to me that you just need to change the main_content css class, but it's hard to tell this way since i can't see which class is which

Comment: try changing    .main_content {
float: right; position: relative;
max-width: 700px;
color:#fff;
}

Comment: infiddle, not easy yar.. because i have lots of code.

Comment: i get it, then find a way to publish it on a hidden address, it would be way easier and convenient.. it's hard to help you this way

Comment: sorry pal, i can't receive now files, is that html page code that long? most important is to show those both contents:   css and html

Comment: Now, i have added margin-top:300px for main-content. so it showed after slidhow..

Comment: And still i am struggling. in my sticky side-bar also have added margin-top;300px.. but when scroll-down, it shows like this.http://s17.postimg.org/gyh9uao4v/Untitled_1_copy.png